# Chrome version 60 SpeechRecognition

Tags: google-chrome

After version 60 webkitSpeechRecognition is disabled for non HTTPS websites.
This is a major issue for developing purposes mainly. Is there a way to bypass/disable this security feature?

The issue is that the popup which is supposed to ask you if you want to access your mic is never displaying on HTTP, but it is on HTTPS.

Setting up HTTPS for DEV is not easy, so I really need a way to bypass this.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, **no**. You can't disable it.

**But**, you can host it though a `localhost` in IIS if you have windows. There's a tutorial on how to do that [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33487zw6.aspx). Once the register it with IIS, you have to add some permissions so you can view in in the browser with `localhost`.

If you are running Linux, you can install Apache2 and just drop it into `/var/www/public_html/{websitename}.` Then you just access it though the browser through `localhost`. There's a tutorial on install Apache [here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/install-and-configure-apache-in-ubuntu/).

There really should be a way to enable the microphone to work through the browser when working with local files. Once you set the `localhost` up though, it's relatively simple to work with.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this locally and worked well without HTTPS. It does not work if the file is being served directly from the filesystem, but with the help of a static file server (I'm using `python3 -m http.server`) I managed to get it working.

Hope it helps!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Teste</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="btn">capture</button>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"> </script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
                recognition.onresult = function(event) { 
                  console.log(event) 
                }
                var started = false;
                $('#btn').click(function(){
                    if (started){
                        recognition.stop();
                        $(this).html('capture');
                        started = false;
                    }
                    else{
                        recognition.start();
                        started = true;
                        $(this).html('stop');
                    }
                });
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: jQuery is not necessary. It is just an old habit of mine :-)

Answer (score -1):

Why not just use a free https cert (like letsencrypt) on your dev server? I mean it's free now, and then you can develop over https.